# Unlink Permission Denied Laravel forge/envoyer

Tags: laravel, permissions, file-permissions, forge

I just updated my digital ocean droplet to use php 7.1 and since then I've been having permission issues. I am deploying with envoyer and used forge to configure the server. Everytime I deploy with envoyer the site goes down and I have to update permissions for the site to come back up `sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache/`

The other issue is with the storage directory. In my application users can upload files, when a user tries to delete a file, the server throws a permission denied error. I can fix this with `sudo chmod 777 storage -R` yes I know this is not the correct way to handle this which is why I am here. So when updating the permissions I am able to delete files that are already on the server, but if I add a new file and try to delete it, the permissions error pops up again and the only way to fix it, is with `sudo chmod 777 storage -R` again.

What is the proper fix so any uploaded files in the future can be deleted? Any help would be appreciated.

`forge@###:~/###/envoyer/current$ ps aux | grep php-fpm
www-data  9232  0.0  7.8 512764 39028 ?        S    22:53   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  9233  0.0  7.7 512864 38936 ?        S    22:53   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
forge    16526  0.0  0.1  12948   912 pts/0    S+   23:13   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
root     22031  0.0  8.3 432756 41984 ?        Ss   May08   0:07 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)`

`\forge@###:~/###/envoyer/current$ ps aux | grep nginx
forge    16640  0.0  0.1  12948   864 pts/0    S+   23:15   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
root     25164  0.0  0.3 149160  1500 ?        Ss   May08   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
forge    25167  0.0  1.2 149776  6492 ?        S    May08   0:03 nginx: worker process`